# error: Connection closed while receiving data Unhandled Exception: Connection closed while receiving data

Tags: flutter

I am trying to integrate Python-based API into my flutter app, to fetch web data, like scrapping, data is coming into Postman but when I run the POST method in the flutter app it runs and gives an id then runs the GET method to get data on that id. But when data come it gives the error  **Unhandled Exception: Connection closed while receiving data**

I have the following rest API written with flask (python)

```
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from Crawler import Crawler



app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
scans = dict()
count = 1


def setScan(result, res):
    scans[result] = res


@app.route('/crawl', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def post():
    url = request.form.get('link')
    start_page = request.form.get('start_page')
    num_pages = request.form.get('num_pages')
    if start_page is None:
        start_page = 1
    if num_pages is None:
        num_pages = 1
    crawler = Crawler(url)
    global count
    global scans
    result = count
    count += 1
    crawler.run_crawler(lambda res: setScan(result, res), start_page, num_pages)
    return {"id": result}


@app.route('/crawl/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def getResult(id):
    if id in scans.keys():
        return jsonify(scans[id])
    else:
        return {"status": "Loading"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

```
import threading
from urllib.parse import urlparse  # parsing urls
import requests  # making requests to website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Crawler:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url  # url of the website
        self.pages = {self.url}  # set of pages
        self.locations = {'Islamabad', 'Karachi', 'Lahore'}
        print(url)
        if "http" in url:
            self.domain = urlparse(url).netloc  # domain name of the website
        else:
            self.domain = url[url.index(".") + 1:]
        self.postings = list()

    def crawl(self, num_pages=1, start_page=1):
        if self.domain == "zameen.com":
            self.crawl_zameen(num_pages, start_page)
        elif self.domain == "graana.com":
            self.crawl_granna_v2(num_pages, start_page)
        elif self.domain == "ilaan.com":
            self.crawl_ilaan(num_pages, start_page)
        else:
            print(f"{self.domain} Webpage not supported")

    def crawl_ilaan(self, num_pages=1, start_page=1):
        cities = ['Lahore', 'Islamabad', 'Karachi']
        for city in cities:
            for i in range(int(start_page), int(num_pages) + 1):
                print(f"Crawling Ilaan page number: {i}\n")
                url = "https://www.ilaan.com/_SearchListingAjax"
                payload = "{\"ic\":\"&ic=Lahore\",\"q\":\""+city+"\",\"ptid\":\"2\",\"tl\":\"1\",\"propertyCategory\":\" Houses \",\"sr\":\"\",\"city\":\"\",\"propertyType\":\"rent\",\"CurrentUrl\":\"house-for-rent?q=&ptid=2&tl=1\",\"pgno\":\"" + \
                          str(i) + " \"}"
                headers = {
                    'authority': 'www.ilaan.com',
                    'accept': '*/*',
                    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    'cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=glvcpa0wa1hkmdbscd5b5yus; _gcl_au=1.1.1521133608.1672521617; _ga=GA1.1.1234506406.1672521618; twk_idm_key=1pCESA-j-i3RBozWQIGuP; _ga_YPP49Z23L5=GS1.1.1672521617.1.1.1672521786.0.0.0; TawkConnectionTime=0; twk_uuid_6373b548daff0e1306d78a3b=%7B%22uuid%22%3A%221.PUjxyVfs9Mcjd5sEod7kopr5BrQot8cCvpTQJSVy7xw9DQha4TpdDvJg1DgGwiiHjcpK6f1J2TvsNdHrciKTgGWsj6fq6dz8iK0DJ49EKrfUvi9gB%22%2C%22version%22%3A3%2C%22domain%22%3A%22ilaan.com%22%2C%22ts%22%3A1672521792461%7D',
                    'origin': 'https://www.ilaan.com',
                    'pragma': 'no-cache',
                    'referer': 'https://www.ilaan.com/house-for-rent?tl=1&ptid=2&pgno=3&ic=%26ic%3dLahore',
                    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
                    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
                    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                }
                req = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
                items = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'float-start col-8'})
                for item in items:
                    link = item.findAll('a')[0]
                    page = f"https://www.ilaan.com{link['href']}"
                    print(f"Crawling Page: {page}\n")
                    res = requests.get(page)
                    bsf = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
                    titleBox = bsf.findAll('h1', attrs={'class': 'opacity-90 font-16'})[0]
                    posting = dict({
                        'url': page,
                        'title': titleBox.text,
                        'location': titleBox.nextSibling.nextSibling.text,
                    })
                    # details
                    details = bsf.find("div", attrs={'class': 'row mb-0 mt3 text-center'})
                    fields = ["id", "area", "purpose", "date", "bedrooms", "bathrooms", "price", "location"]
                    fieldsDetails = []
                    for child in details:
                        detail = child.text.strip()
                        if len(detail) > 0:
                            fieldsDetails.append(detail)
                    posting['details'] = dict(zip(fields, fieldsDetails))
                    imagesBox = bsf.find('div', attrs={'class': 'splide__list'})
                    images = []
                    imgBox = imagesBox.findAll('img', attrs={'class': 'img-fluid'})
                    for img in imgBox:
                        image = img['src']
                        if image[:4] == 'http':
                            images.append(image)
                    posting['media'] = images
                    self.postings.append(posting)
        pass

    def crawl_granna(self, num_pages=1, start_page=1):
        cities = ['islamabad', 'rawalpindi', 'lahore']
        for city in cities:
            for i in range(int(start_page), int(num_pages) + 1):
                print(f"Crawling granna page number: {i}\n")
                url = f"https://www.graana.com/_next/data/0Qm8AcPOlM2s6IO6V9RNo/residential/for_rent/{city}/all/1.json?offset=30&page={i}&subtype=residential&purpose=for_rent&city=islamabad&areas=all&ids=1"
                print(url)
                payload = {}
                headers = {
                    'authority': 'www.graana.com',
                    'accept': '*/*',
                    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                    'baggage': 'sentry-environment=Staging,sentry-release=0Qm8AcPOlM2s6IO6V9RNo,sentry-transaction=%2F%5Bsubtype%5D%2F%5Bpurpose%5D%2F%5Bcity%5D%2F%5Bareas%5D%2F%5Bids%5D,sentry-public_key=c255164d1e7144b5a93adf2553c49a82,sentry-trace_id=4d8470d72fef46289c24a46b72ef999b,sentry-sample_rate=0.5',
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.984580374.1671639286; _ga=GA1.1.1940448186.1671639287; lhc_per=vid|46e86cb4d2faad1a962c|hnh|1672162939; _ga_4CNKWK86H3=GS1.1.1672512375.4.1.1672512959.0.0.0; __cf_bm=Z5b01rElnJVtNnqNgKQ8gl1BhLBUQoX6aU_PwObp3No-1672513333-0-AROQpdSKrXQBvbdyoZbQ2DDp/CMFF/kS/2CE6fHzGgD5JBi/3bJbxg5tNS/rNx9TaS1MvJjOXeDTYDMM9O2cN2z4JahQ1liaV7/Vhmo6VZM+KfzUwk3T3AP7okwyuWKo/CPPRTxFU05nY+JWSR8MooBFbIHCWuJHjwI2xMN6eop+fBaIrP7vou9Kd6ek5vvLww==',
                    'pragma': 'no-cache',
                    'referer': 'https://www.graana.com/residential/for_rent/Islamabad/all/1',
                    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
                    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
                    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                    'sentry-trace': '4d8470d72fef46289c24a46b72ef999b-bc25d6041c1c672f-1',
                    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                    'x-nextjs-data': '1'
                }
                response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
                print(response)
                data = json.loads(response.text)
                listings = data["pageProps"]['propertyServer']['listings']['items']
                self.postings.append(listings)
        pass

    def crawl_granna_v2(self, num_pages=1, start_page=1):
        cities = ['Islamabad', 'Rawalpindi', 'Lahore']
        for city in cities:
            for i in range(int(start_page), int(num_pages) + 1):
                try:
                    print(f"Crawling granna page number: {i}\n")
                    url = f"https://www.graana.com/residential/for_rent/{city}/all/{i}"
                    print(url)
                    headers = {
                        'authority': 'www.graana.com',
                        'accept': '*/*',
                        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                        'baggage': 'sentry-environment=Staging,sentry-release=0Qm8AcPOlM2s6IO6V9RNo,sentry-transaction=%2F%5Bsubtype%5D%2F%5Bpurpose%5D%2F%5Bcity%5D%2F%5Bareas%5D%2F%5Bids%5D,sentry-public_key=c255164d1e7144b5a93adf2553c49a82,sentry-trace_id=4d8470d72fef46289c24a46b72ef999b,sentry-sample_rate=0.5',
                        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                        'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.984580374.1671639286; _ga=GA1.1.1940448186.1671639287; lhc_per=vid|46e86cb4d2faad1a962c|hnh|1672162939; _ga_4CNKWK86H3=GS1.1.1672512375.4.1.1672512959.0.0.0; __cf_bm=Z5b01rElnJVtNnqNgKQ8gl1BhLBUQoX6aU_PwObp3No-1672513333-0-AROQpdSKrXQBvbdyoZbQ2DDp/CMFF/kS/2CE6fHzGgD5JBi/3bJbxg5tNS/rNx9TaS1MvJjOXeDTYDMM9O2cN2z4JahQ1liaV7/Vhmo6VZM+KfzUwk3T3AP7okwyuWKo/CPPRTxFU05nY+JWSR8MooBFbIHCWuJHjwI2xMN6eop+fBaIrP7vou9Kd6ek5vvLww==',
                        'pragma': 'no-cache',
                        'referer': 'https://www.graana.com/residential/for_rent/Islamabad/all/1',
                        'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
                        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
                        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                        'sentry-trace': '4d8470d72fef46289c24a46b72ef999b-bc25d6041c1c672f-1',
                        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                        'x-nextjs-data': '1'
                    }
                    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data={})
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
                    script = soup.find('script', attrs={'id': '__NEXT_DATA__', 'type': 'application/json'})
                    data = json.loads(script.text)
                    listings = data["props"]["pageProps"]['propertyServer']['listings']['items']
                    self.postings.append(listings)
                except:
                    pass
        pass

    def crawl_zameen(self, num_pages=1, start_page=1):
        cities = [1, 2, 3]
        for city in cities:
            for i in range(int(start_page), int(num_pages) + 1):
                print(f"Crawling Zameen page number: {i}\n")
                url = f"https://www.zameen.com/Homes/Islamabad-{city}-{i}.html"
                req = requests.get(url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
                items = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': '_7ac32433', 'aria-label': "Listing link"})
                for link in items:
                    page = f"https://www.zameen.com{link['href']}"
                    print(f"Crawling Page: {page}\n")
                    res = requests.get(page)
                    bsf = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
                    titleBox = bsf.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'b72558b0'})[0]
                    posting = dict({
                        'url': page,
                        'title': titleBox.findChildren()[0].text,
                        'location': titleBox.findChildren()[1].text,
                    })
                    # details
                    detailsBox = bsf.find("ul", attrs={'class': '_033281ab', 'aria-label': 'Property details'})
                    for li in detailsBox.children:
                        pair = li.findChildren("span")
                        posting[pair[0].text] = pair[1].text

                    imagesBox = bsf.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'image-gallery-thumbnails'})
                    images = []
                    for imgBox in imagesBox:
                        images.append(imgBox.find('img', attrs={'role': 'presentation'})['src'])
                    posting['media'] = images
                    self.postings.append(posting)
        pass

    def run(self, cb, start_page=1, num_pages=1):
        self.crawl(num_pages, start_page)
        try:
            cb(self.postings)
        except:
            cb({"status": "Failed"})

    def run_crawler(self, cb, start_page=1, num_pages=1):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=(cb, start_page, num_pages))
        thread.start()
```

This is the flutter Provider code......

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/retry.dart';

import '../model/PropertyApiModel.dart';

class PropertyApiProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool isLoading = false;
  http.Response? result;
  var id;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  List<PropertyApiModel> propertyModel = [];
  Future deletedocs() async {
    final instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final batch = instance.batch();
    var collection = instance.collection('propertydata');
    var snapshots = await collection.get();
    for (var doc in snapshots.docs) {
      batch.delete(doc.reference);
    }
    await batch.commit();
    print("deleted");
  }

  int i = 0;
  var data;

  Future<dynamic> getData(String id) async {
    try {
      print("getting data...");
      var client = RetryClient(http.Client(), retries: 2);

      result = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5000/crawl/$id'),
          headers: {"Keep-Alive": "timeout=50, max=2"}).timeout(
        const Duration(seconds: 50),
      );
      if (result!.statusCode != 200) {
        result = await client.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5000/crawl/$id'),
            headers: {"Keep-Alive": "timeout=50, max=2"});
      }

      print("response status code: ${result!.statusCode}");
      if (result!.statusCode == 200) {
        var body = jsonDecode(result!.body);

        print("data: ${body.toString()}");
        print("data length: ${body.toString().length}");
        if (body.toString().length == 17) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 2));
          return await getData(id.toString());
        } else {
          await deletedocs();

          for (Map pp in body) {
            print("firebase running");
            propertyModel.add(PropertyApiModel.fromJson(pp));
            PropertyApiModel propertyApiModel = PropertyApiModel(
              added: propertyModel[i].added,
              Location: propertyModel[i].citylocation,
              area: propertyModel[i].area,
              baths: propertyModel[i].baths,
              bedrooms: propertyModel[i].bedrooms,
              location: propertyModel[i].location,
              media: propertyModel[i].media!,
              price: propertyModel[i].price,
              purpose: propertyModel[i].purpose,
              title: propertyModel[i].title,
              type: propertyModel[i].type,
              url: propertyModel[i].url,
            );
            await _firestore
                .collection("propertydata")
                .add(propertyApiModel.toJson())
                .then((value) {
              print("idddd ${value.id}");
            });
            if (i < result!.body.length) {
              print("adddddddddddd");
              i++;
              print(propertyApiModel);
            } else {
              FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
              readdata() async {
                final data = firebaseFirestore.collection('propertydata');
                final snapshot = await data.get();

                if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
                  print(snapshot.toString());
                }
              }
            }
          }
          isLoading = false;
          notifyListeners();
          return body;
        }
      } else {
        throw Exception(
            "Failed to fetch data, status code: ${result!.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error: ${e.toString()}");

      rethrow;
    }
  }

  getId(String url) async {
    try {
      print("making post request...");
      http.Response response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:5000/crawl"),
          body: {'link': url, 'start_page': '1', 'num_pages': '2'});
      print("response status code: ${response.statusCode}");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var body = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        id = body['id'];
        print("iddd   $id");
        getData(id.toString());
        notifyListeners();
        return id.toString();
      } else {
        throw Exception(
            "Failed to get id, status code: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("error: ${e.toString()}");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you are using wrong data for `jsonDecode`.

The response data is actually in the `response.bodyBytes`.

And Since you cannot directly convert `bytes` to `json` with `dart`, convert `bytes` to `String` first then decode the `String` using jsonDecode.

So... don't use `response.body` use `response.bodyBytes`.

I have modified your code so that it uses `response.bodyBytes`

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // Get body bytes from response
  final bytes = response.bodyBytes;
  // Convert bytes to String then decode
  final body = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(bytes));
  id = body['id'];
  print("iddd   $id");
  getData(id.toString());
  notifyListeners();
  return id.toString();
} else {
  throw Exception("Failed to get id, status code: ${response.statusCode}");
}
```

Comment: still getting the same error..... I was already getting an id.... but not data against that id